# window.open show log file in window

Tags: javascript

I have a file that has a file extension **log**.

I would like to display the contents of this log file in a new window (in chrome). However when I call my **window.open** function like so :

```
window.open('/log/eppsta.log ', "", "height=800,width=1200,toolbar=0,menubar=0");
```

I get the new window, but the file is downloaded as an attachment, and my window looks like so :

[image]

How do I get my log file content to display (as normal text) in my new browser window?

Comment: Try to reset the association of *.log to your notepad or set it to open with Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to change the HTTP headers for the file, you could grab the log with either a [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), then use document.write on the new window to write the log to the window:

```
fetch('/log/eppsta.log')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(text => 
    window.open('', '', 'height=800,width=1200,toolbar=0,menubar=0')
          .document.write(text)
  )
  .catch(err => throw err) // Handle any errors
```

If you want to have it print out with monospacing, like a log, maybe wrap the `body` in the document.write call with `<pre>` tags like this: `.document.write('<pre>' + body + '</pre>')`

Comment: I get: res.body() is not a function. Should i just leave the (..) out?

Comment: Sorry, it's actually res.text(). Fixed my answer.

Comment: this does not seem to always work. Quite often this erases my current window with the file that it is loading.... :/

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the HTTP headers in the response include:

`ContentType: text/plain`

That should do the work.

Comment: how do you set the conetenttype to text/plain on oa window.open command?

Comment: This solution is for the server side: if you serve that file with that HTTP header, the browser will just show the text. If you don't want to tinker with the server, then the accepted answer will fit you better

Answer (score -1):

Browsers these days will just download the files if you do stuff like that, you need to do, I don't think there is really any way of doing this with javascript so you should use PHP for this, so you would have to do the following (lets call this file log.php):

```
$file = file_get_contents('/log/eppsta.log');
echo $file;
```

and use the js to open the new window:

```
window.open('log.php', "", "height=800,width=1200,toolbar=0,menubar=0");
```

This should work ;)